# Extrapolating UK Census Data

Tags: census

I have currently been given the task of collating the demographics for a few places that reside in the county of Flintshire, North East Wales, UK.  My first search for a place named Holywell gave me more than everything I need which came from www.nomisweb.co.uk; however, the data is from the 2011 consensus which is dated.

I searched the consensus 2021 roadmap and according to this, it wont be publicly available till 2023. I also searched for alternative sites that would hopefully give me something more up-to-date but they all are mostly referring to the 2011 report.

I've titled this question with the word "extrapolate" as I literally wondered if one could predict a broad estimate for 2021 with the 2011 and 2001 reports for demographics?  Or it could be a case of I am not doing a very good job with my search terms.

Any replies/help will be much appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

MSOA and LSOA Flintshire screen capture of Excel files

[image: MSOA/LSOA]

Comment: There are published [mid-year population estimates](https://statswales.gov.wales/Catalogue/Population-and-Migration/Population/Estimates/Local-Authority/populationestimates-by-localauthority-year) for Flintshire so you could use that as a basis for local extrapolation.

Comment: Or you could try to look at the [MSOA](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/middlesuperoutputareamidyearpopulationestimates) and [LSOA](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/lowersuperoutputareamidyearpopulationestimates) covering Holywell (the match will not be exact as the areas are not administrative but may be more locally relevant than numbers for the whole county)

Comment: Thanks for that, I started by looking at the MSOA and LSOA excel sheets.  However, how does one marry up the MSOAs and LSOAs with particular places e.g. Holywell, etc.?  I have added a screen grab of both Excel files so you can see all the references to Flintshire.  Yes I am definitely more interested in local places as opposed to Flintshire as a whole.  How does one get additional up-to-date info like ethnicity, welsh speaking, etc.  Its overkill but here is a great example: https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/reports/localarea?compare=W38000132 but its based upon the 2011 census

Comment: There are MSOA and LSOA maps.  For example [this](https://gov.wales/docs/statistics/lsoamaps/lsoa.htm) has Holywell Central, Holywell East and Holywell West LSOAs.  For the others, there will not be accurate local data  until the 2021 census is published, but you might reasonably guess that local ethnicity numbers might have roughly changed in proportion to population change locally and in proportion to ethnicity proportion changes at a national level.

Comment: Thanks for the link that will be helpful for finding the figures for such areas like Holywell, etc.  Is it possible you could provide me an example of a proportional change just for demo purposes as that would be extremely helpful.  When you mean national, do you mean North Wales or more local than that?  Apologies for all the questions!